# Pandas dataframe, in a row, to find the max in selected column, and find value of another column based on that

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
>>>import pandas as pd
>>>df = pd.DataFrame({'x1':[20,25],'y1':[5,8],'x2':[22,27],'y2':[10,2]})
```

```
>>>df
      x1  y1  x2  y2
   0  20   5  22  10
   1  25   8  27   2
>>>
```

X and Y pair together. I need to compare y1 and y2 and get the max in every row. And find the corresponding x.
Hence the max of row [0] is y2 (=10), and the corresponding x is x2 (=22). The second row will be y1
(=8) and x1(=25).
Expected result, new columns x and y:

```
   x1  y1  x2  y2   x   y
0  20   5  22  10  22  10
1  25   8  27   2  25   8
```

This is a simple dataframe I made to elaborate on the question. X and Y pairs, in my case, can be 30 pairs.

Comment: yes. compare y1 and y2.  if y1 is the max, i need to get its corresponding x: x1. If y2 is the max, I need to get x2.

Comment: Kindly add the expected output dataframe

Answer (score 2):

```py
# get a hold on "y*" columns
y_cols = df.filter(like="y")

# get the maximal y-values' suffixes, and then add from front "x" to them
max_x_vals = y_cols.idxmax(axis=1).str.extract(r"(\d+)$", expand=False).radd("x")
# get the locations of those x* values
max_x_ids = df.columns.get_indexer(max_x_vals)

# now we have the indexes of x*'s in the columns; NumPy's indexing
# helps to get a cross section
df["max_xs"] = df.to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), max_x_ids]

# for y*'s, it's directly the maximum per row
df["max_ys"] = y_cols.max(axis=1)
```

to get

```py
>>> df

   x1  y1  x2  y2  max_xs  max_ys
0  20   5  22  10      22      10
1  25   8  27   2      25       8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the help of .apply function.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'x1':[20,25],'y1':[5,8],'x2':[22,27],'y2':[10,2]})
y_cols = [col for col in df.columns if col[0] == 'y'] 
x_cols = [col for col in df.columns if col[0] == 'x'] 

def find_corresponding_x(row):
    max_y_index = np.argmax(row[y_cols])
    return row[f'{x_cols[max_y_index]}']

df['corresponding_x'] = df.apply(find_corresponding_x, axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the function below. remember to import pandas and numpy like I did in this code. import your data set and use **Max_number** function.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'x1':[20,25],'y1':[5,8],'x2':[22,27],'y2':[10,2]})

def Max_number (df):
    columns = list(df.columns)
    rows = df.shape[0]
    max_value = []
    column_name = []

    for i in range(rows):
        row_array = list(np.array(df[i:i+1])[0])
        maximum = max(row_array)
        max_value.append(maximum)
        index=row_array.index(maximum)
        column_name.append(columns[index])
    
    return pd.DataFrame({"column":column_name,"max_value":max_value})
```

returns this:

| row index | column | max_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | x2 | 22 |
| 1 | x2 | 27 |

Answer (score 0):

if x1 column comes first and then y1, then x2, y2 and so on, you can just try:

```
a = df.columns.get_indexer(y_cols.idxmax(axis=1))
df[['y', 'x']] = df.to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), [a, a - 1]].T
```

Answer (score -1):

this is one solution:

```
a = df[df['y1'] < df['y2']].drop(columns=['y1','x1']).rename(columns={'y2':'y', 'x2':'x'})
b = df[df['y1'] >= df['y2']].drop(columns=['y2','x2']).rename(columns={'y1':'y', 'x1':'x'})

result = pd.concat([a,b])
```

if you need to keep order then maybe add another column with original index and sort by it after concatenation

Comment: I will create two more columns: the max y and its correspodning x. The example is to illustrate the problem. The df can be 30 pairs, mentioned in the bottom of the question. Hence, df['y1'] < df['y2'] can't be used.

Comment: and is it possible for you to use a 3 dimensional data frame? I think you have a 3 dimensional data projected on two dimensions. If you have to keep it in two dimensions then the only way I can think of is the "non pandas" way to loop through the rows and set the max for each row

Comment: My problem does have 3 dimension. But the 3rd one has no values. If (x,y) or (x,y,z) being a point, there are lots of points in my problem.

Answer (score -2):

I hope it works for your solution,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x1':[20,25],'y1':[5,8],'x2':[22,27],'y2':[10,2]})
df['x_max'] = df[['x1', 'x2']].max(axis=1)
df['y_max'] = df[['y1', 'y2']].max(axis=1)
df
```

Comment: X and Y come as a pair. I only get the max of y1 and y2 and then take the corresponding x. If y1 is the max, i will get x1. If y2 is the max, I will need x2.

Comment: I updated my answer, hope you already found your solution

Comment: df['y_max'] = df[['y1', 'y2']].max(axis=1) is fine. But I need the corresponding x. So df['x_max'] = df[['x1', 'x2']].max(axis=1) is no use. 'x_max' has to follow 'y_max'. For example, if y2 is max of y1 and y2, i have to get x2. I didn't comment your solution unuseful.